# How to build and deploy Xcode project to the new Apple's TestFlight via command line

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

After the launching of Apple's Testflight service, all I need to submit the build is click "Archive" and "Submit", Xcode only asks which team to use for provisioning. I wonder, is there way to do this via command line? I know that xcodebuild can build an ipa file, but I haven't found how to submit build to iTunesconnect. (Xcode 6.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

This project claims to allow you to upload the IPA binary, screenshots and more via a command line:

https://github.com/krausefx/deliver

deliver can upload ipa files, app screenshots and more to the iTunes Connect backend, which means, you can deploy new iPhone app updates using the command line.

"Upload new builds to the new Apple TestFlight"